# How long does it take a Widow Mine to attack an enemy unit?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have been trying to incorporate the new [Widow Mine](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/widow-mine) unit into my army. When I burrow the Widow Mine their is a circle that indicates it's attack radius. However, I have noticed that when enemy units enter into it's attack radius, the Widow Mine's ability `Unstable Payload` doesn't activate instantly.

Instead the Widow Mine takes "a few seconds" and then fires it's missile. This has become increasingly perplexing as I have seen:

- Zerglings run partly into and then out of the firing radius of a Widow Mine without the ability triggering.
- Zerglings on Creep with the Metabolic Boost run **through** the attack radius of a Widow Mine without it detonating.

How long does an enemy unit need to be in the attack radius of a Widow Mine for the Unstable Payload ability to be triggered?

Comment: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=403878 ... 1.5 in-game seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Widow Mine takes 1.5 in game seconds to lock on to an enemy and fire.

This translates to different real time seconds based on game speed:

```
Slower - 2.49s
Slow   - 1.875s
Normal - 1.5s
Fast   - 1.241s
Faster - 1.088s
```

[Source](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=403878)